# Why are many cAdvisor metrics not being scraped?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, cadvisor

We have a Kubernetes cluster and are using Prometheus/Grafana to collect and view metrics information. I am currently looking into container metrics, that as far as I can tell, are managed and provided by cAdvisor (https://github.com/google/cadvisor). I assume cAdvisor is installed and running in the cluster, although I haven't been able to verify this (any suggestions on how to determine that would be much appreciated).

On the cAdvisor Prometheus documentation page (https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/storage/prometheus.md) it lists the various metrics that are available. There are some differences between the set of metrics that Prometheus "knows" about in the cluster vs. the set listed in the above link, but I'm guessing this could be due to differences in the versions of cAdvisor.

What's more important to me at this point is the fact that there are a number of metrics that are *not* being scraped by Prometheus. This phenomenon extends beyond cAdvisor, but I'll focus just on the cAdvisor relevant metrics.

The following metrics are "known" by our instance of Prometheus and are listed in the link above. None of them are being scraped by Prometheus - I get an empty query result. As far as I can tell, the remaining "cAdvisor metrics" *do* return a result.

```
container_cpu_cfs_throttled_seconds_total
container_cpu_load_average_10s
container_cpu_system_seconds_total
container_cpu_user_seconds_total
container_file_descriptors
container_fs_io_current
container_fs_io_time_seconds_total
container_fs_io_time_weighted_seconds_total
container_fs_reads_merged_total
container_fs_sector_reads_total
container_fs_sector_writes_total
container_fs_writes_merged_total
container_memory_mapped_file
container_memory_swap
container_spec_cpu_period
container_spec_cpu_quota
container_spec_cpu_shares
container_spec_memory_limit_bytes
container_spec_memory_reservation_limit_bytes
container_spec_memory_swap_limit_bytes
container_tasks_state
container_threads_max
```

Why are there so many metrics that are not being scraped? In many cases, there seem to be related metrics, where some are scraped and some are never scraped. An example: `container_threads` is scraped, while `container_threads_max` is not.

I'm assuming that metrics that start with `container` are cAdvisor metrics, but maybe I'm mistaken. Could it be that the metrics I see being scraped are defined somewhere else and that ones not being scraped are "real" cAdvisor metrics and they're perhaps not being scraped because either cAdvisor is not installed, or metrics for cAdvisor have not been enabled?

**UPDATE**:

A comment from @DazWilkin may have directed me to information that might explain some of the unscraped metrics.

I took a look at my Prometheus "kubelet" `ServiceMonitor` and found a "drop" list that seems to match the list of unscraped metrics listed above. Below is the relevant section.

```
  - bearerTokenFile: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
    honorLabels: true
    metricRelabelings:
    - action: drop
      regex: container_cpu_(cfs_throttled_seconds_total|load_average_10s|system_seconds_total|user_seconds_total)
      sourceLabels:
      - __name__
    - action: drop
      regex: container_fs_(io_current|io_time_seconds_total|io_time_weighted_seconds_total|reads_merged_total|sector_reads_total|sector_writes_total|writes_merged_total)
      sourceLabels:
      - __name__
    - action: drop
      regex: container_memory_(mapped_file|swap)
      sourceLabels:
      - __name__
    - action: drop
      regex: container_(file_descriptors|tasks_state|threads_max)
      sourceLabels:
      - __name__
    - action: drop
      regex: container_spec.*
      sourceLabels:
      - __name__
    - action: drop
      regex: .+;
      sourceLabels:
      - id
      - pod
    path: /metrics/cadvisor
    port: https-metrics
    relabelings:
    - action: replace
      sourceLabels:
      - __metrics_path__
      targetLabel: metrics_path
    scheme: https
    tlsConfig:
      caFile: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
      insecureSkipVerify: true
```

I'm a little concerned with the last `action` block, which looks like it will drop everything. Maybe I'm interpreting the RegEx incorrectly. I'll also have to say I don't know the significance of the `sourceLabels` section.

Comment: cAdvisor is bundled with the kubelet binary

Comment: If you are using a managed version of Kubernetes, which service? If you are using Prometheus Operator, it's likely (don't know) that you'll need to enable scraping of the additional metrics.

Comment: It appears that (by default) the Prometheus Operator [drops](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/blob/ba50502da954f9b10471131c0fba0eadeb890e70/manifests/kubernetesControlPlane-serviceMonitorKubelet.yaml#L66) e.g. `container_threads` (!) and `container_threads_max`

Comment: If cAdvisor is part of Kubelet, what happens if I were to install, say, the cAdvisor Helm chart (e.g., https://github.com/ckotzbauer/helm-charts)? Does the Helm chart override the built-in one? Will there be conflicts? Not clear what might happen in this scenario.

Comment: Now that's an interesting bit of info. I knew nothing about the Prometheus Operator having all of these drop rules. Might explain some of the issues I've been having.

Comment: It's a different question (;-)) but, if you were to install cAdvisor again, you would be duplicating the work on the Node but it would work. You'd be able to address the metrics from the Kubelet's version via its endpoint and the standalone cAdvisor version via its endpoint. If you are using the Prometheus Operator, you'd need to add `ServiceMonitor` or `PodMonitor` to scrape the duplicate cAdvisor metrics

Comment: OK, sounds like something I don't want to get into, unless absolutely necessary.